# Python Multiprocessing Process class lifecycle

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am using Python's multiprocessing [Process](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#the-process-class) class for a project to handle a function in a separate process. My question is, what happens when does the function in a separate process do its job? Is it that the process remains idle, or is process killed by the end of the function? Also, will there be any issues with giving the process/function a heavy load?

The code block is like this:

```
p = Process(target=function, args=[status.json])
if not p.is_alive():
    p.start()
p.join()
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using the [Process class](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#the-process-class), then the process starts when you call [start()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process.start), and terminates when the target function completes, or you call the `Process` object's [terminate()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process.terminate) method. The process does not consume execution resources after terminating, but it will remain in the [process table](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4880555/2615940) as a [zombie process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zombie_process) until you call [join()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process.join).

Regarding your concerns about putting a "heavy load" on the new process, it shouldn't have any effect. The multiprocessing library launches full-blown independent processes, so they operate largely the same as your main process does. Now whether or not the `Process` class is really the appropriate solution to your problem is hard to say since "heavy load" can mean many different things. If your tasks are IO intensive, the [threading module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html) may be a better choice. If you are performing the same tasks on many different objects, [process pools](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool) may be a more appropriate choice. But a "heavy load" in and of itself shouldn't cause problems.